# Angularjs Material Check all and Uncheck all Not working?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have created Multi select dropdown with Slectall and Deselect all option .
Here i have all checkbox which will do select all and deselect all but it's working only once after that its not working can anyone help me on this below is my code .

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedUser" multiple="" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value'}">
    <md-optgroup >
        <md-option ng-value="" ng-click="doSelectedUser()">all</md-option>
        <md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in newusers">{{ user}}</md-option>
    </md-optgroup>
</md-select>
```

below is my controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('sandbox', ['ngMaterial']);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

 $scope.selectedUser =[];
 $scope.newusers = ['A','B','c']

 $scope.doSelectedUser = function () {
 if($scope.selectedUser.length > 0)
 {
    $scope.selectedUser = [];
} else {
    $scope.selectedUser = $scope.newusers; }
}

});
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ltr9bpm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go with this

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedUser" multiple="" ng-model-options="{trackBy: 
'$value'}">
 <md-optgroup>
 <md-button layout-fill  ng-click="doSelectedUser()">
 {{(selectedUser.length == newusers.length)?'Deselect All':'Select All'}}
 </md-button>
 </md-checkbox>
 <md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in newusers" >{{ user}}</md-option>
 </md-optgroup>
</md-select>
```

and

```
 $scope.selectedUser = [];
 $scope.newusers = ['A', 'B', 'c']
 $scope.doSelectedUser = function () { 
 if ($scope.selectedUser.length == $scope.newusers.length) {
 $scope.selectedUser = [];
 } else {
 $scope.selectedUser = $scope.newusers;
 }
 }
```